# Javascript ternary operator with object

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-operator

I came across a piece of code I am trying to figure out, the code basically stores the occurrence of the amount of time a word appears in a text document, so the function **countWordsIntext** takes in the desired text and displays the word and the number of occurrence in the text, 
e.g
would: 3
but: 5
very: 6

while looking at the function that counts the word in the text I cant figure out how the conditional tenary operation is supposed to work. An explanation would be very much appreciated

```
var wordCounts = {};

 function countWordsInText(text) {
    var words = text.toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .split(/\W+)
                .sort();
    for(var index in words) {
    var word = words[index];
    if(word) {
     wordCounts[word] =
        (wordCounts[word]) ? wordCounts[word] + 1 : 1;
       }
   }
} 

function display()
{
  for (var index in wordCounts)
   console.log(index + ': ' + wordCounts[index]);
}
```

I don't understand how the `wordCounts[word]` object property is updated.

Comment: This code?   `wordCounts[word] =....`  Maybe the line break is confusing you.  If wordCounts[word] exists, increment it, otherwise set it to 1 (because it's a new entry).  And it is not an array, it is an object where the members can be accessed using a dictionary/array type syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have

```
var foo = {};
```

The line that is confusing you would be

```
foo.bar = foo.bar ? foo.bar + 1 : 1; // line A
```

Ask yourself

1. What is `foo.bar` at the start? It is *undefined*, we didn't give `foo` a property *bar*
2. What is `foo.bar` after the first time line A is executed? It is `1`; `foo.bar` was *undefined* which is *falsy* so the ternary operator gave us back `1`
3. What is `foo.bar` after the second time line A is executed? It is `2`; `foo.bar` was `1` which is *truthy*, so the ternary operator gave us back `foo.bar + 1`

Line A can be repeated until you run out of numbers or the world explodes

Writing it like this is a way to solve the `undefined + 1` problem, which would give `NaN`

---

An equally valid solution (which I find a bit cleaner to read personally) would be to do

```
foo.bar = (foo.bar || 0) + 1;
```